# Passing data about a realm object to a fragment

Tags: android, realm

I'm am working with a one to many relationship in my application that I am writing with Realm.io  In the application UI I'm creating an activity which displays information about the parent object at the top and then uses a ViewPager to display information about the children in fragments.  With SQLite I would have passed information about foreign keys to the fragment so that the fragment could query the database and find the children.

What I'm not sure of is how to pass that information along inside of Realm.io.  Is there a mechanism to say I want all of the objects that have a relationship with another object?  Can I pass references to realm objeects through the parcelable interface?  I can do a query to against all of the identifying attributes of the parent and then grab the children directly, but that seems error prone.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: The response below is effective when working with activities. Another alternative would be to go with a fragment oriented design where you could pass data through a method from a base activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Christian from Realm here.
The Realm core supports the notion of backlinks which is what you are after, but they have not been exposed in the Java API yet, which unfortunately means you cannot use them yet. So instead you will have to manually maintain some sort of ID on you child objects.

I would suggest adding a String property called ID or similar to your child objects and give them a value from UUID.getRandomUUID().toString() when creating them. Those strings can be added to either a Intent or a Bundle and parsed to you fragments, where you can query the child object using the UUID.